# How can I resize one div without applying it to settings that have same name? css

Tags: html, css, liferay

I have this css:

```
.col-md-9 {
    float: left;
    width: 80%;
}

.scheduler-view-agenda { 
    width: 270px;
}

.yui3-widget-bd {
    width: 270px; 
    height: 390px;
}

.calendar-portlet-mini-calendar {
    width: 270px; 
}

#portlet_com_liferay_calendar_web_portlet_CalendarPortlet {

}
```

However line `.yui3-widget-bd {width: 270px; height: 390px;}` changes all settings etc etc to 270x390, but I need it to apply only one div class. It's liferay so I can't just change html and be done with it, only custom css can be added. Any help is appericated!

Comment: This question is not answerable without knowing anything about the html structure. Can you please add the markup and say which div exactly you want to reach?

Comment: @Markai <div class="yui3-widget-bd"> <- this

Comment: @bernieg What more content do you have around that div? If all you have is one class, and it's being used on multiple elements.
You will need to find something more unique to the one element with the class you want to target. You could then target all elements with that class, that also lies closest to any other object/is the X number of element from top etc.

Comment: @Darloz heres whole html of div: https://codeshare.io/2jjRw3

Comment: Please edit your question for additional information and don't use external resources.